# listview data images repeat on fast scroll down

Tags: android, image, android-listview

I have this adapter that I load with data from the internet. It displays the wrong images for a split second before displaying the right one if I scroll down quickly. The corresponding text next to the images however does not do this. It's more obvious when it download even more data on the fly. Please help me debug this. Here's what the listview looks like:

[image: The listview]

The categoryAdapter is initialized with a list of data containing only textview data. When categoryAdapter's getView() is called, it downloads the image from a url through asynctask. A OnScrollListener downloads 12 more articles (again only text) when the bottom of the listview is reached. Here is getView(). Note that I thought recycling the old views was the problem, so I tried to set the image to null quickly before changing the imageview's drawable to the new image so that I wouldn't see the old one. This worked for not seeing the bug if I scroll up quickly, but not if I scroll down quickly. What could be the issue?

```
class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter{...
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, final ViewGroup viewGroup){
    // crate a new rowItem object here
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row;

    if (view == null) row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, viewGroup, false);
    else row = view;

    // Get the description, image and title of the row item
    TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) row.findViewById(R.id.progressBarSingleRow);

    /* On getting view, set this to invisible until loaded. (issue before: old image seen
       before new image on fast scroll) Mostly fixed by this, but on fast scroll down, still
       shows a little */
    image.setImageDrawable(null);

    // Set the values of the rowItem
    SingleRow rowTemp = articles.get(i);
    title.setText(rowTemp.title);
    description.setText(rowTemp.description);

    String s = "null";
    if (rowTemp.image != null) s = "not null";
    Log.e("ImageLog", "Item " + Integer.toString(i) + ", is " + s);

    // Load image into row element
    if (rowTemp.image == null) {    // download
        // Prepare prepped row objects in single holder object for fetchCategoryImageTask
        AdapterObject holder = new AdapterObject();
        holder.title = title;
        holder.description = description;
        holder.image = image;
        holder.pb = pb;

        new FetchCategoryImageTask(rowTemp, holder).execute();
    }
    else {                          // set saved image
        // Cropping image to preserve aspect ratio
        image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        image.setCropToPadding(true);
        image.setImageBitmap(rowTemp.image);
    }

    return row;
}
```

Just in case, here's a little of fetchCategoryImageTask()

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    image.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return (sr.imageURL != null) ? downloadBitmap(sr.imageURL) : null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Bitmap b) {
    // imageView image
    // Preserve aspect ratio of image
    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    image.setCropToPadding(true);
    image.setImageBitmap(b);

    // Make image visible
    image.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

    // Save image to SingleRow object for categoryAdapter's getView()
    sr.image = b;
}
```

Comment: On scroll android will keep calling the getView method of your adapter which recreates the listItem, First you should try to properly use ViewHolder Pattern for your listView and then Cache Images, you can check the android documentation on how to implement LruCache

Comment: I'm not averse to trying that, it sounds like good practice. I have a lot of images though so what do you think about the universal image loader? I thought asynctask might have to be replaced later (android tutorial told me that asynctask could cut out if I changed the phone orientation).

Comment: Universal ImageLoader Library will definitely use an AsyncTask to fetch the image, but using it isn't a bad idea if you are not willing to go through the process of implementing it yourself. ImageLoader basically handles all the problem for you, e.g caching. When Screen Orientation changes the activity is recreated but async task runs on the background, so i really don't see asynctask cutting out.

Comment: Alright. I read [making listview scrolling smooth](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html), [caching bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html), and [managing bitmap memory](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html). What do you think of the disk cache and soft references?

Comment: Errrrm, i think the choice is yours really, it prolly depends on the max memory you want for your cache size. The android doc indicates that WeakReferences and SoftReferences are not recommended anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is from the comments, so I'll post it here. I'm going to use the viewHolder pattern to not have to look up the views every time I get the row and cache images with LRU cache. Here are the reference links: [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html), [Caching bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html).

Answer (score 2):

What is happening here is that ListViews reuse views. So it reuse a view that already has an image. I recommend you to use Volley library or ImageLoader library to solve this problem, it is easy to define a placeholder to show while the image is being downloaded.

So instead of use Asynctask, use the code below:

```
private void showImage(View view, String imageUrl) {
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()//
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.image_placeholder) 
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.image_placeholder) 
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_placeholder) 
                .cacheInMemory(true) 
                .cacheOnDisk(true) 
                .build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrl, imageViewType, options);
    }
```

Universal Image Loader library: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: How much changes in my implementation will it take to transfer over from the asynctask for downloading images to this? Will this be simpler than implementing a viewholder pattern?

Comment: I like a lot to use libraries and I think It is pretty easy... below the code that you set the content, like title.setText(rowTemp.title), description.setText(rowTemp.description); you set your imageView and the imageUrl... showImage(image, imageURL).